# series convergence. Dirichlet test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum(-1)^{\lfloor\frac{n^3+n+1}{3n^2-1}\rfloor}\frac{\ln(n)}{n}$$
I thought about using Dirichlet test. $\ln(n)/n$ is a decreasing sequence that tends to 0 but I have problem with proving it. I also can
t tell anything about $(-1)^{\lfloor\frac{n^3+n+1}{3n^2-1}\rfloor}$.

Comment: You have "problem with proving" that "ln(n)/n is a decreasing sequence that tends to 0"? Then one might start with that. What did you try to solve this specific part of the question?

Comment: Starting with $ln(n)/n>ln(n+1)/n+1$ or $(ln(n)/n)*((n+1)/ln(n+1))>1$. It leaded me nowhere.

Comment: Your must have something else in your arsenal of tools! What about derivatives?

Comment: We cannot use derivatives :<

Comment: Rubbish. Who said so?

Comment: Lecturer? We can use only tools that were introduced on the lecture.

Comment: We just need the Bernoulli inequality in the form $\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\leq\frac{1}{n}$, see below.

Answer (score 3):

To prove that $\frac{\log(n)}{n}$ is decreasing, notice that:

$$\frac{\log(n+1)}{n+1}=\frac{\log n}{n+1}+\frac{\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{n+1}\leq \frac{\log n}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$$
hence if $n> e,$
$$\frac{\log(n+1)}{n+1}< \log n\left(\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n(n+1)}\right)=\frac{\log n}{n}.\tag{1}$$
To prove that
$$ (-1)^{\left\lfloor\frac{n^3+n+1}{3n^2-1}\right\rfloor}\tag{2} $$
has bounded partial sums, notice that:
$$ \frac{n^3+n+1}{3n^2-1} = \frac{n}{3} + \frac{4n+3}{9n^2-3} $$
and:
$$ \forall n\geq 3,\qquad 0<\frac{4n+3}{9n^2-3}<\frac{1}{5}, $$
so for any $n\geq 3$ we have that $(2)$ behaves like the sequence: 
$$ \ldots, -1,-1,-1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,\ldots \tag{3}$$
that obviously has bounded partial sums.